# User interface with animation and effects

Tags: java, flash, html, animation, graphics

I want to program a language learning Program for kids. I want it to have animations, quizzes with drag and drop and  a lot of graphic effects. 
I want to know which language is good for client side and which is good for desktop application.

I am programming with java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With AS3/Flex you could use the same classes for a web application and an AIR application (desktop). Just import your classes in different projects then and generate both a web client and a desktop app.

Comment: thanks for your answer.. i want to ask you which IDE you use. ist it rich of effects?

Comment: Well, my IDE (flashdevelop) is pretty much a text editor, and it has an infinity of effects since you know how to code them. The way you ask for effects makes me think you are looking for a wysiwyg interface (something like powerpoint ?). The closest you can get to this in AS3 is by using Adobe Flash, but I'm not sure of what you are really looking for.

Comment: i have searched now a little and found that adobe flash cs4 have a bone tool that can for example make a walking animation very easy. could you make it with code? would that not take so much time

Comment: No, this is purely an animation helper, but I wouldn't call it an effect. and again it depends on what you are looking for. Flash is used by many animation studios for cartoons, so you can rely on it if you want to animate stuff.

Comment: thank u for ur answer.
so the ideal way i think then is to program in flashdevelop and use cs for helping me to create some animations. is that right expression?

Comment: You can combine these two just like you say!